# Use one parameter or the other only & use specified file in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parameters, scripting

I'd like to do two things with my batch script.

The first being use one parameter or the other only. I.e., the following:

```
C:\> foo.bat file.txt /A
/A commands here.

C:\> foo.bat file.txt /B
/B commands here.

C:\> foo.bat file.txt /A /B
ERROR: Either /A or /B can be specified only.

C:\> foo.bat file.txt /B /A
ERROR: Either /A or /B can be specified only.
```

And the second being use the specified file to do commands. I.e, the following:

```
C:\> bar.bat file.txt /A
file.txt has been archived.
```

I did attempt to write some code to do this, but I'm not getting too far. Here's my work so far:

```
if /i [%~f1] == [FILE] set usedfile=[FILE]
if /i [%1] == [] goto error
if /i [%2] == [/A] set "A_or_B=A"
if /i [%2] == [/B] set "A_or_B=B"
```

And then %usedfile% would just be copied to another location with `copy`.

Comment: Read (and follow) https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html and https://ss64.com/nt/if.html if you are _not even sure how to start_.

Comment: This will require writing cmd script (.bat file) code. You get mutual exclusion for free by using parameter sets in PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I got a bit further. I've added my code so far into the original question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the first parameter should be a filename, but I am not quite sure. This should get you closer.

```
C:>TYPE asdf.bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET EXITCODE=0

if /i [%~f1] == [FILE] set usedfile=[FILE]
if /i [%1] NEQ [] (SET "usedfile=%~1" & GOTO NextSwitch)
ECHO ERROR: File not specified.
SET EXITCODE=1
GOTO TheEnd

SET "OPT_A="
SET "OPT_B="
:NextSwitch
IF [%2] EQU [] (GOTO SwitchesDone)
if /i [%2] == [/A] (
    IF [%OPT_B%] NEQ [true] (SET "OPT_A=true") ELSE (GOTO SwitchError)
)
if /i [%2] == [/B] (
    IF [%OPT_A%] NEQ [true] (SET "OPT_B=true") ELSE (GOTO SwitchError)
)
if /i [%2] == [/B] set "OPT_B=true"
SHIFT
GOTO NextSwitch

:SwitchError
ECHO ERROR: Either /A or /B can be specified only.
SET EXITCODE=2
GOTO TheEnd

:SwitchesDone
ECHO NB: usedfile is %usedfile%
ECHO NB: OPT_A is %OPT_A%
ECHO NB: OPT_B is %OPT_B%

:TheEnd
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

Here are a couple of runs.

```
21:30:52.27  C:\src\t
C:>asdf.bat adsf /B /A
ERROR: Either /A or /B can be specified only.

21:31:01.01  C:\src\t
C:>asdf.bat adsf /A
NB: usedfile is adsf
NB: OPT_A is true
NB: OPT_B is
```

Comment: Yes, the first parameter must be a valid file. I haven't fully read over the code yet, but I did try it out and it seems to be working as expected! I'll report back when I can on my results.